# Как реализовать 2д передвижение на наклонной плоскости?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня возникла огромная проблема с 2д движением по наклонной поверхности. Чтоб было понятнее, я на всякий случай объясню то, что мне надо. К примеру у нас есть горка с наклоном в условные 30 градусов. Когда я на нее подымаюсь, то при подъеме теряю скорость, а на вершине горки я просто прыгаю как на трамплине, а когда спускаюсь с нее, то персонаж спускается прыжками. Надо сделать так, чтобы он был, как бы сказать, прижат к плоскости и двигался параллельно плоскости. Уже просмотрел куча гайдов, но они то ли не подходят для меня, то ли что-то не то со мной. Вот что я имею сейчас:

```
private void Move()
{
    float targetVelocityX = DetermineTargetVelocityX();

    Vector2 targetVelocity = new Vector2(targetVelocityX, _rigidbody.velocity.y);
    _rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.SmoothDamp(_rigidbody.velocity, targetVelocity, ref nullVector, _smoothTime);

    bool isWalking = _moveDirection != Vector2.zero;

    if (isWalking && Mathf.Sign(_moveDirection.x) != Mathf.Sign(transform.localScale.x))
        Flip();
}

private float DetermineTargetVelocityX()
{
    float targetVelocityX = _moveDirection.x * _moveSpeed;

    if (_isCrouching)
        targetVelocityX = _moveDirection.x * _crouchSpeed;

    if (_isDashing)
        targetVelocityX = _moveDirection.x * _dashSpeed;

    return targetVelocityX;
}
```

Comment: Вам надо взять полную скорость (которая у вас сейчас по оси Х), взять угол наклона плоскости, домножить полную скорость на синус угла наклона - это будет скорость по вертикали и на косинус угла наклона - это будет по горизонтали. возможно я перепутал между собой. угол наклона должен быть не плоскости, а именно вашей траэктории (например можно вдоль плоскости перпедндикулярно наклону ехать и угол наклона траэктории будет 0)

Comment: @Darth, можете показать как это будет выглядеть в коде?

Comment: [Как ПРАВИЛЬНО сделать передвижение в Unity? Нормали поверхностей + Чистый код на C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puPjNRJMmOc&t=95s)